# Sqlite is updating table really slowly for simple multiplications

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm using python3 and sqlite3 to do a relatively simple transformation on a large table (1,1 GB in the DB and about 7 Million rows in this tble). The aim is to multiply two fields with -1 in all rows.

My query is

```
"UPDATE 'channel_data' SET 
    'x_uncompensated_m'=-1*'x_uncompensated_m',
    'y_compensated_m'=-1*'y_compensated_m'"
```

The updating seems to take forever, so something like multiple minutes. The journal file grows to about 540 MB while the original database has about 1,1 GB. Any hints how to increase performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating *every* record.  This is horrendously expensive.  All the operations need to be logged -- plus locking and lots of other overhead.

For this reason, updating every row is not really recommended.

One option is to "batch" the updates -- do, say, 10,000 at a time.  Another is to recreate the table:

```
create table temp_channel_data as
    select . . .,  -- all the other columns
           -1*x_uncompensated_m as new_x,
           -1*y_uncompensated_m as new_y
    from channel_data;
```

Then backup the table somehow (so you don't make a big mistake).  And empty it and re-populate it:

```
truncate table channel_data;

insert into channel_data ( . . . )  -- list the columns here
    select . . .                    -- list the columns here
    from temp_channel_data;
```

Bulk inserts are much faster than updates, because they do not require logging every row.